# How many different way are there for creating GUI in Android Programming?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android Programming, and I saw via tutorial that we can create GUI using main.xml or via Graphical Layout, but it is not that much flexible, like I choose a button and want show it on my chosen pixels of screen (as I do CGReckMake in iPhone programming), any suggestion or better way to get flexibility in Android GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android i know two way to design GUI by XML or By JavaCode but my suggestion is you should use XML because it is easy compare to javacode learning about layouts and view then you find it is very easy.

Comment: but I want to set x and y axis as I want, but mail.xml won't allow u except particular layout, so  ,,,,?

Comment: I have design lot of screen in andorid same as iPhone no problem i am facing till date.

Comment: But I want it suitable for all devices, then can u guide me in a way so that I get concept behind it?

Answer (score 4):

As Android supports different hardware with different specs related to screen side, density, etc. it is not recommended to do pixel-precise layout of elements on the screen.

There is an [AbsoluteLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) which allows you to specify exact location for the elements, but it's use is discouraged if you want your app to run on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [droiddraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) also.